# Why does clicking "No Action Needed" on an already-deleted post fail the audit?

Tags: support, review-queues, review-audits, first-post-review

While going through the `First Post` queue over the past few days, I have noticed a trend that has plagued me with a 2 day review ban. Numerous times I have stumbled across "Test" posts to see if you are actually reading them.

While I agree it is important to make sure the reviewer is paying
attention, what is the correct way to "correct" a "bad" test post?

When trying to correct some of these first posts, by clicking the edit button, it is revealed to me the post has been deleted. I will then either click `No Action Needed` or if i remember the trap, `Skip`. If the post was a test and you click `No Action Needed`, even after attempting to edit the post, you are delivered a review ban.

- Why is it that clicking on the edit or flag button on tests in the `First Post` queue not inform you that the particular post is a test and that you passed?
- Is there a way to actually pass tests in that particular queue?

Comment: `you are delivered a review ban` Only if you have a history of failed audits.  If you don't, you just get a failed audit and then move along.

Comment: I would not be surprised if this has been asked before, but I don't see an answer to this question in either of proposed dupes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the post is so bad that it merited deletion, editing *doesn't* make sense as an action to pass the audit.  We don't want people polishing turds, nor do we want people saying that no action is required on posts that are so bad they need to be deleted.

To pass the audit you should indicate that the post should be deleted (in your case, through a flag), for whatever reason applies to it, whether that be spam, if it's spam, not an answer, if it's not an answer, etc.

Comment: I guess the problem I have is that I view the post being deleted as already solving the problem so there "No action needed".

Comment: @Ryan And now you know that you *shouldn't* say that posts that merit deletion require no action, you should say that they should be deleted if they merit deletion.

Comment: While I find it odd and redundant to request the deletion of a post that has already been deleted. I can understand where you are coming from.

Comment: @Ryan are you saying you've seen post shown as "deleted" in the "First Posts" queue? I've not seen such posts in any queue - indeed I've seen audits that turned out to be deleted posts but they were never presented to me as deleted when shown in the queue.

Comment: The post is shown visibly, However;  when you attempt to edit the post, it reports the post as already deleted